# Автоматическая авторизация пользователя на сайте

Tags: php, cookie, сессия, авторизация, backend

Я новичок в бэкэнде и в этом всём разбираюсь не очень. Делаю небольшой макет сайта, так, для опыта и практики. Хочу осуществлять автоматическую авторизацию пользователей после выхода из браузера и тому подобных ситуаций. Можно, конечно, записывать в куки пароль и логин и сверять их с бд, но хочется немного углубиться в безопасность. Хэшированый пароль тоже не самая надёжная вещь, как понял. Через поиск в интернете либо захлёбывался в терминологии, либо находил такие же решения.

Для начала хотел обойти ситуацию с простым копированием кук на другое устройство. Использовать сессию не вариант, т.к. она удаляется (хотя я могу чего-то не знать). Можно записывать в куки не логин-пароль, а токен. Но его также можно скопировать. Судя по тем же статьям из интернета прявызать к ip тоже плохо, т.к. он может меняться. Как вариант - сохранить какой-то токен и периодически его менять. Но в таком случае авторизацию можно будет сделать только на одном устройстве, а хочется чтобы нет. Так как можно это реализовать?

Comment: Просто используй сессий, они вечные.

Comment: @singlesly, а разве сессия не удаляется после выхода из браузера?

Comment: Вроде пока лог аут не сделаешь она висит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ слишком длинным для комментариев оказался, напишу тут. Сохранять в куках логин и пароль действительно плохая идея. Как вариант - сохраняется у пользователя случайный токен и, возможно, логин(зашифрованный), в БД логин/токен/IP/иноформация о браузере. Сделать IP необязательным параметром при проверке, а все остальное - обязательное совпадения, у каждого устройства будет свой токен, даже если будет одинаковый логин, это даст неплохой уровень безопастности. По крайне мере, простым копированием кук взломать не получится. А дальше дополнительные параметры проверки уже на ваше усмотрение.

[Ссылка на сайт, где создают подобную систему регистрации](https://ruseller.com/project.php?id=5)

Comment: А если у каждого устройства свой токен, а их кол-во неограничено, то как сохранять это в бд? Там же вроде нет массивов

Comment: Отдельными записями. Если у вас 3 устройства вошли в аккаунт, у них будет 3 разных токена, а в базе будет 3 разных записи. Не стоит их объединять. Их и проще удалять будет при выходе из аккаунта на каком-либо из устройств, и искать в базе.

Comment: Хм, а каким образом их все-таки хранить в базе? Создавать отдельный столбец для каждого токена не вариант, а больше как-то ничего в голову не приходит. В отдельной таблице тогда тоже придется создавать столбцы.
Единственное, если при загрузке доставать из бд строку с токенами, разбивать на массив, работать с этим массивов, а потом опять сохранять в строку в бд, но может есть что-то проще?

Comment: А, еще только что придумал, что можно в отдельную таблицу под один ид записывать токены и ип адреса в отдельные строки, это примерно так должно работать?

Comment: Доставать, разбивать, сохранять, слишком долго. Я, когда реализовывал, создавал отдельную таблицу, со столбцами токен/логин/IP/браузер. Без привязки к id(если вы про id пользователя в другой таблице, то тогда так можно), потому что там данные будут постоянно меняться. Если вы боитесь совпадений, то их там не будет, все строки будут уникальными хотя бы в одном параметре. Строки в таблице будут независимы. Даже, если они все будут одного аккаунта, просто с токенами с разных устройств.

Comment: Ну да, я примерно это и имел в виду. То есть при авторизации на новом устройстве создаём запись с тем же логином/ид во второй таблице, и по логину/ид после этого вытаскиваем все остальное и сверяем